# Not getting json response in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function fn(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "http://www.enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/NTES",
        data: "action=getTrainForDate&trainNo=16649&trainStartDate=11/04/2014&t=1397216860215&18q1xp3lm5=1ptur1oxbz1i5vwea0u61397214250740",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    }   
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="fn();"> hi </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use Ctrl+K to format your code

Comment: Once you got your code indented, why not ask a question ?

Comment: it may be CORS problem , javascript is not allowed to get ressources from hosts other than the current host

Comment: Looks like the server is borked. Plugging that url into the browser returns `(function(){location.reload();})()`

Answer (score 4):

The URL you are requesting returns `(function(){location.reload();})()`, which is not JSON, JSONP or any form of useful data.

Answer (score -1):

Just to update you need to use `jsonp` instead of `json` because you're going to get CORS error otherwise. Updated code is

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "http://www.enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/NTES",
    data: {"action" : "getTrainForDate", "trainNo" : "16649", "trainStartDate" : "11/04/2014", "t" : "1397216860215", "18q1xp3lm5" : "1ptur1oxbz1i5vwea0u61397214250740"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Note there's nothing wrong in your way of sending data as string, I just prefer object way.
Now when you make a call you'll end up getting this message (and not data)

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://www.enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/NTES?callback=jQuery2119973546624…1397216860215&18q1xp3lm5=1ptur1oxbz1i5vwea0u61397214250740&_=1397220999300".
```

This is where problem is. If you hit the formed URL, it'll give you JavaScript function as a response and no data. This is what you get as a response

```
(function(){location.reload();})()
```

I think, server expects unique token (identified by `"18q1xp3lm5" : "1ptur1oxbz1i5vwea0u61397214250740"` set), for each request. If condition is not met, it sends reload request to the browser.

Since the call is made through AJAX, it's not able reload the page, but due to reused token, there's no result.